# When cloning from git server i get message: perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: c++, git, perl, github, encoding

My OS is Linux Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. I use command to clone files from git server:

```
$ git clone basecamp:some_acount
```

and getting this warning:

```
Cloning into 'some_acount'...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (13/13), 7.73 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I have two questions:

1. will i have a problems with my files (static c++ libraries with
   exstension ".a")?
2. how can i fix this warning?

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate I closed with talks about ssh. Your git command effectively ssh-es into the remote (there are no git servers, there are just remotes) and that machine doesn't like your locale settings. The second option at the bottom of the accepted answer should help. Your files are not affected, this is just annoying.